# How to trigger the change in the number of daily events on react big calendar?

Tags: react-big-calendar

I'm using react big calendar and I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the change in the number of displayed event per a single day. To clarify, let us assume that we have a calendar with an height of 500px. Per rbc specifications, the number of events in a single day is computed on the basis of this size. However, if we change the size of the calendar to 1000px (e.g. adding a class, or changing the min-size, or in any other way), the number of events in a single day should increase.

This is not happening, with the number of events in the day remaining the same. I've tried to re-render the calendar and change the events array, but neither had any effect.
It appears that this number is computed on the first page render and then never recomputed. Is there a way to trigger a recomputation?

Thank you